# moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Tags: python, pytube

[Terminal screenshot of pytube installed][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OlFm.png pytube is installed but when code it does not locate module but gives an error

Comment: Make sure you've installed it on the correct python version. You can try
```python3.8 -m pip install pytube```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 3.8 in my system and I have installed pytube using the pip coomand but when I call the module in my project it says module not found .That is the error.And also when I check pytube is installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a virtual environment for your project, which is good. However, you might have not installed the package in said virtual environment.

To do that execute the following in terminal

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python -m pip install pytube
```

Which should download the the module in the virtual environment.
if you have a `requirements.txt` file you could add `pytube` to it and then run

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```